# Wamp Server. Aestan tray menu error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I click on the mysql console option in the wamp server. And i get the following error-

```
Aestan Tray Menu
Could not execute menu item(internal error)
[EAccessViolation] Access violation at address 7EFA664B. Read of address FFFFFFFF.
```

The console doesn't start.Some links suggest to install ms visual c++ redistributable version for similar errors.
I did that but didn't work out.

Comment: Try doing it the long way and starting a command prompt in the wamp/bin/mysql/<version>/ folder and running mysql.exe. I get an error like that periodically trying to use the WAMP menu, when I restart it goes away. http://bmehla.wordpress.com/2011/04/30/run-mysql-command-line-with-wamp/

Answer (score 0):

Install both Visual C++ and .NET framwork.

Comment: You can download the MSVC++ redistributable from the Microsoft download centre.  I think installing both those pieces is somewhat overkill.